# How to build a single android widget that when stretched, it reveals more buttons?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, widget

I needed to launch a single button widget. Once launched, when I stretch the width, I want to be able to display two more buttons. Similar to on the image below. I would start with widget [A]. Once I stretch, I want to be able to see [B] and [C]. When I resize, I want to only show the single widget. I would like to avoid building two different widget. I tried changing the visibility of the other two buttons based on when the widget width gets resized.

Layout size 1 * 3 grid. When I hide those 2 buttons, I'm left with void space of 2 grids in that layout.

Thank you for your help!

override fun onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetId: Int, newOptions: Bundle?) {
val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.coffee_logger_widget)

```
    val minWidth = newOptions?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH)
    val maxWidth = newOptions?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)
    val minHeight = newOptions?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT)
    val maxHeight = newOptions?.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)

    if (minWidth != null) {
        if (minWidth > 100) {
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.espresso_button, View.VISIBLE)
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.long_button, View.VISIBLE)
        } else {
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.espresso_button, View.GONE)
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.long_button, View.GONE)
        }
    }

    appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)

}

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

<TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonVerticalSpace" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
    style="@style/WidgetTextView.Big" />

<TextView
    style="@style/WidgetTextView"
    android:text="@string/grams" />

<TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonVerticalSpace" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonHorizontalSpace" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ristretto_button"
        style="@style/WidgetBeverageButton" >

        <ImageView
            style="@style/WidgetButtonImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ristretto" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/WidgetButtonText"
            android:text="@string/ristretto_short" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonHorizontalSpace" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/espresso_button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/WidgetBeverageButton"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/WidgetButtonImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_espresso" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/WidgetButtonText"
            android:text="@string/espresso_short" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonHorizontalSpace" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/long_button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        style="@style/WidgetBeverageButton"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/WidgetButtonImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_long_coffee" />
        <TextView
            style="@style/WidgetButtonText"
            android:text="@string/long_coffee_short" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonHorizontalSpace" />


    <!-- Buttons go here -->

</LinearLayout>

<TextView style="@style/WidgetButtonVerticalSpace" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coffee_quote"
    style="@style/WidgetQuote" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set B and C's `visibility` to `GONE`, that will make them "disappear" from the layout so it can shrink to just contain `A`.

By the way, if you add `animateLayoutChanges = "true"` to that layout's XML, the buttons will fade in and out nicely and the layout will stretch and shrink. You might need to change the order you make `B` and `C` `VISIBLE` or `GONE` to make it look right, depending on what you're doing

Oh also, it depends on your layout too - it needs to be `layout_width = "wrap_content"` so it can shrink to just wrap the remaining `A`. If you're using a `GridLayout` with a fixed size, you'd need to change that width in code, or replicate its look with a `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`. It depends on what you're actually doing!

Comment: hmm it didn't work. I updated my original post with the code i'm testing this with. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't post the code for ``RemoteViews`` so I have to guess, but you're passing a layout resource to it - are you inflating that layout, and then finding views in that and setting their visibility with ``remoteViews.setVisibility``? That's not the same set of views your activity/fragment is displaying, when you inflate a layout you create a whole new set of view objects. If you want to affect the stuff being displayed, you'll need to pass the activity/fragment's ``view`` to your helper class. Also ``animateLayoutChanges`` needs to be on the layout that will be growing/shrinking I think!